# select data without current year from table

Tags: mysql

i want to select data current year data should ignored table structure ( `year` , `month` ,  `temp_air` , `dry_temp`) 
Select * from table where year(date)='not current year'`
what should i add to "not current year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try like this:

```
where year(date)!=YEAR(CURDATE())
```

instead of

```
where year(date)='not current year'`
```

You may select whichever columns you want to select and ignore the rest.

```
SELECT month, temp_air, dry_temp from table where year(date)!=YEAR(CURDATE())
```